# Hadoop reducer cleanup function

Tags: hadoop

In hadoop reduce code, I have a cleanup function which prints the total count, but it print twice. I think this is because it's printing the count of key+values and the count alone, but I'm not sure.

My code has this:

```
protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            Text t1 = new Text("Total Count");
            context.write(t1, new IntWritable(count));
        }
```

inside the reducer class and the output is:

```
Total Count     9477
Total Count     4738
```

Comment: did u set combiner class as the same reducer?

Comment: This code is inside the reducer class. I have set map and reduce classes separately....

Comment: Can u check homany reduce tasks triggred

Comment: It is only one. Though if it is a duplicate issue, because of being repeated twice, it should have printed only the same numbers right, but it displays two different numbers in each statement.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanup method is called at the end of each task. So I assume you are running 2 reducers in the code. therefore 2 outputs